# How can create the SSLSocket key in the code?

Tags: java, sockets

in java, client must use the key file to connect server.how can i init it in the code? 
i want server create the key in code. What to do?
ths for u Answer

Answer (score 1):

> In java, client must use the key file to connect server.

No. It needs a *truststore* file that contains either the server's certificate or the certificates of one or more of that certificate's signers.

> How can I init it in the code?

You can't. The question doesn't make sense. The idea is that you have certificate material obtained *offline* that gives you a reason to trust the server. Or possibly the other way around, if your server requires client authentication. In either case, creating it dynamically doesn't make any sense.

Comment: yep,but some times ,in Distributed system,client don't know the certificate  update.

Comment: Then you should use a security system that will cope with that situation. What you are proposing breaks SSL security completely. You may as well not be using SSL at all. Note the word 'offline' in my answer. You can't exchange the material that establishes the security over the connection over the connection you are trying to secure. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

> i want server create the key in code.

maybe this helps you: http://code.google.com/p/xebia-france/wiki/HowToGenerateaSelfSignedX509CertificateInJava